# Excel - Pivot Table - Count of occurance

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a Table as below:

[image: The Table]

Basically, this table shows the status of the employees of a company from Dec-15 to Mar-16.

Actually, I want to use pivot table to provide me a summary table as below:

[image: Required summary table]

My question is, how to use "pivot table" to produce the above expected result table? My boss insist to use pivot table because he think that pivot table can provide him a better data grouping view (has the expand button) and he can use the slicer as filtering.

Hope my question is clear enough for your understanding. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With your present table, you most probably can't. Why? Because the data you have is already stored in column (dates and status).

So the best option would be to convert your table to something that look like a data base, here is the example for Peter and the output :

[image]

With such a table, you'll need to configure your Pivot table like this :

**Rows**

1. Statuts
2. Grade
3. Roles

**Columns**

1. Month

**Values**

1. Count of Name